# Standardizing Typography for Italicized Font Style in Tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to standardize typography on a website that my team is building and we have decided the following custom utility classes in Tailwind. Now, for `small-italicized`, we also want the text to be italicized, however, from what I have researched, `fontSize` only takes in `lineHeight`, `letterSpacing` and `fontWeight`. If I wanted to also make `small-italicized` italicized, where would that go?

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/shared/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        'heading-1': ['1.5rem', { fontWeight: 700 }],
        'heading-2': ['1.375rem', { fontWeight: 700 }],
        'heading-3': ['1.125rem', { fontWeight: 700 }],
        'bold-body': ['1rem', { fontWeight: 700 }],
        body: ['1rem', { fontWeight: 400 }],
        small: ['0.875rem', { fontWeight: 400 }],
        'small-italicized': ['0.875rem', { fontWeight: 400 }],
        label: ['0.875rem', { fontWeight: 300 }],
        'graph-label': ['0.75rem', { fontWeight: 500 }],
        'graph-number': ['0.625rem', { fontWeight: 400 }],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I tried adding a `fontStyle` property inside of `small-italicized` as follows:

```
'small-italicized': ['0.875rem', { fontWeight: 400, fontStyle: 'italic' }]
```

However, this does not apply the desired font style. I've also tried reading the Tailwind documentation regarding this but I don't think I've found any that addresses this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `font-style` in a CSS file that is processed by Tailwind like:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .text-small-italicized {
    font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

Or as a utility class added via a Tailwind plugin:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  // …
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss/plugin')(({ addUtilities }) => {
      addUtilities({
        '.text-small-italicized': {
          fontStyle: 'italic',
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
}
```

Furthermore, you could extrapolate the Tailwind plugin route further in such a way that you could have everything in one place if you wanted to.